# iFrame display content from another server

Tags: iis, iframe

I had created a simple portal site for our internal users, just a CSS menu with our internal web services which then displayed in an iFrame.  Worked well so far.

Our helpdesk software was GLPI running on APACHE on the same server and had no issues.  We recently upgraded to the latest version and in the meantime I moved it to our new web apps server and switched to IIS.  The 'portal' is still hosted on the old server.

When I updated the javascript for the iFrame to point to the new address, it looked like it worked, I could get the login screen for GLPI.  After logging in however I just get stuck at a white screen.  If I try it in IE I get the message:

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame 
>        To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be
>   displayed in a frame.
>        What you can try: 
>       Open this content in a new window

It doesn't seem to be the iFrame itself as I can get the login page.

My question is, can anyone give me some ideas on where to look at this issue? I've checked the IIS logs on both sides and see no errors, GLPI reports no errors,  neither does PHP.

GLPI is on IIS 8 on Server 2012
The 'portal' is on IIS 6 on server 2003
GLPI running on PHP 5.3.0

EDIT: I've looked into the X-FRAME issue and I'm pretty sure this is not it,  servers are on the same domain and I am able to get to the login screen of the second server through the iFrame, just no content after that.  If it was an issue with the frame or permissions I would expect to not get to the site at all?

The only header response currently in IIS is 'X-Powered-By --> ASP.NET'  am I looking in the wrong spot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is returning an `X-Frame-Options` header [used to prevent ClickJacking](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx). That header must be removed (or updated with an `Allow-From` directive that lists the framing page's origin) in order for the target page to be rendered as a subframe.